# four Weeks data - group by

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by

I have the following tables with their respective data:

```
FORECAST:
- ITEM
- FORECAST_WEEK_DATE
- FORECAST

SALES:
- ITEM
- SALES_WEEK_DATE
- SALES
```

The WEEK_DATE column has records for every end-of-week date like:
7/02/2015
15/02/2015
and so on.

I want to bring the results from the both the tables so that the result like:

```
ITEM FORECAST_TOTAL SALES_TOTAL
001       23             45
```

for the total of latest 4 weeks data.

How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75fb8/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE FORECAST ( ITEM, FORECAST_WEEK_DATE, FORECAST) AS
          SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01',                     1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL  '7' DAY, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '14' DAY, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '21' DAY, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '28' DAY, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '35' DAY, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '42' DAY, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01',                     3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL  '7' DAY, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '14' DAY, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '21' DAY, 8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '28' DAY, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '35' DAY, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE SALES (ITEM, SALES_WEEK_DATE, SALES) AS
          SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01',                     3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL  '7' DAY, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '14' DAY, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '21' DAY, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '28' DAY, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '35' DAY, 8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '42' DAY, 11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01',                     7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL  '7' DAY, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '14' DAY, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '21' DAY, 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '28' DAY, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL '35' DAY, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

This will get the data for the latest 4 weeks in the table for each item:

```
WITH ordered_week_data AS (
SELECT f.ITEM,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY f.ITEM ORDER BY FORECAST_WEEK_DATE DESC ) AS RN,
       f.FORECAST_WEEK_DATE AS WEEK_DATE,
       FORECAST,
       SALES
FROM   FORECAST f
       INNER JOIN
       SALES s
       ON ( f.ITEM = s.ITEM AND f.FORECAST_WEEK_DATE = s.SALES_WEEK_DATE )
)
SELECT ITEM,
       MAX( WEEK_DATE ) AS LAST_WEEK_DATE,
       SUM( FORECAST ) AS FORECAST_TOTAL,
       SUM( SALES ) AS SALES_TOTAL
FROM   ordered_week_data
WHERE  RN <= 4
GROUP BY
       ITEM
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75fb8/1/0)**:

```
| ITEM |             LAST_WEEK_DATE | FORECAST_TOTAL | SALES_TOTAL |
|------|----------------------------|----------------|-------------|
|    1 | February, 12 2015 00:00:00 |             22 |          27 |
|    2 | February, 05 2015 00:00:00 |             18 |          21 |
```